# Formatted Logging with parameters not working

Tags: visual-c++, logging, variadic-functions

I'm writing in VC++ with VS2012 pro and trying to get my logger to output something like this

```
03/26/2013    Registry()+
03/26/2013    Registry::LoadDWORD("VersionNumber")+;
03/26/2013    Registry(3)-
```

with the following lines of code

```
RegistryHelper::RegistryHelper()
{
    LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry");
}
bool RegistryHelper::LoadDWORDValue(char* entry, UINT defaultValue, UINT& returnValue)
{
    LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry::LoadDWORD", entry);
    //Code to get DWORD

    LogWriter::WriteEnd("Registry::LoadDWORD", returnValue);
    return true;
}
```

The code I have thus far is this

```
void LogWriter::WriteStart(const char* log, ...)
{
    tcout << log << "(";

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, log);
    vfprintf(stderr, log, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);

    std::wcout << ")+" << EOL;
}
```

as a test I wrote this.

```
LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry", "Something", "else", "Start", "STop");
char* entry = "VersionNumber";
LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry", entry);
LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry");
```

but i am only getting back

```
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry()+
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry()+
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry()+
```

but i am expecting back

```
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry(Something, else, Start, STop)+
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry(VersionNumber)+
2013-03-26.11:41:15 Registry()+
```

With some playing around with it (mainly grabbing code from online and try a few different things) I've been able to make it say `Registry(Registry)+` but is about as close as I've come. (I was using a while loop and checking for NULL) I'm somewhat new to VC++ and very new to using params (sorry i'm a C# guy). This is as far as I've gotten in about 1 hour of playing around with it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're writing "Registry()+" to stdout.  You're writing your log message to stderr.  They are two separate streams.  Are you sure you're reading "stderr"?  Maybe you're *logging* correctly, but just not looking at the right output?

Comment: @paulsm4 good point because i only redirect wcout and wcerr.. sooo what is my wcout output?

Comment: so as far as answering my self some I had 2 options. One is to use a string formated text (which might still be a option), or 2 is to use a integer counter in my arguments since va_arg does not know how many elements it has, and a NULL check does not work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use variable-number-of-arguments feature on top of `*printf` function, but you are not passing any format specifier (like `%d`, `%s`) when you are calling `WriteStart`.

A call should be like:

```
LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry %s", entry);
```

Also, you need not to hard-code the function name to indate from where the log is being generated. The statement:

```
LogWriter::WriteStart("Registry::LoadDWORD", entry);
```

Can easily be replaced with:

```
LogWriter::WriteStart(__FUNCTION__, entry); // I am ignoring the format-specifier here
```

`__FUNCTION__` will be replaced by fully-qualified function name by the preprocessor.

Moreover, you can also craft a macro that will take care of all this:

```
#define WRITE_LOG(_smsg) \
   LogWriter::WriteStart(__FUNCTION__ , _smsg);
```

And use it:

```
WRITE_LOG("Your log message"); // Again, I ignore format-specifier here and in macro.
```

If you are using macro, and using variable-argument function with format specifier, you can use `__VA_ARGS__` along with macro itself.

Comment: I did not know about the `__FUNCTION__` it is amazing! Thank you very much for that tip. That helps me so much. I'll give the macro a try and see what it is like. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
std::cout << log << "(";

va_list argptr;
va_start(argptr, log);
vfprintf(stdout, log, argptr); // use same stream here!
va_end(argptr);

std::cout << ")+" << EOL;
```

Comment: I did try this at one time, but was not getting the desired output. And as was brought out by Ajay I would have had to give it a string format such as `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

Better - just pass whatever output stream you wish to use as an argument:

```
void LogWriter::WriteStart(FILE *fp, const char* log, ...)
{
    fprintf (fp, "(");
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, log);
    vfprintf(fp, log, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    fprintf (fp, ")\n");
}
```